# S_ISREG not working on listing function

Tags: c, stat

I am having some trouble counting only the regular files in a directory.

This is my code:

```
int show_regular_files(char ** path) {
    DIR * dp = opendir(*path); // open the path                                                              
    char d_path[BUFSIZE]; //                                                                               
    struct dirent *ep;
    struct stat sb;
    int number=0;
    int rv;
    if (dp != NULL){
        while (ep = readdir (dp)){
            sprintf(d_path,"%s/%s ",*path,ep->d_name);
            rv= stat(d_path, &sb);
            if(rv<0)
            continue;
            else{
                if((sb.st_mode & S_IFMT)==S_IFREG){ // checks if a file is regular or not
                    if(sb.st_mode & S_IXOTH || sb.st_mode & S_IXGRP){// search permission  & group owner of the file
                        number++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        perror("can't open the file ");
            closedir(dp); // finally close the directory                                                                                                                                                                           
    return number;
}
```

It always prints 0 unless I remove the REGULARFILE condition check and stat line, then it lists all the files in the directory.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?  How do you know it's the `S_ISREG` macro that's failing you? It's in the title yet it's not in your posted code.

Comment: This code shouldn't find any files. You have an extra space in your `d_path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
sprintf(d_path,"%s/%s ",*path,ep->d_name);
                     ^
```

where you have an extra space at the end which results in `stat()` calls failing. You need to remove that space.

By the way, avoid `sprintf()`. Use `snprintf()` instead.

Comment: the problem was indeed the extra space, kudos to you!